# Python: Remove Duplicate Items from Nested list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
mylist = [[1,2],[4,5],[3,4],[4,3],[2,1],[1,2]]
```

I want to remove duplicate items, duplicated items can be reversed. The result should be :

```
mylist = [[1,2],[4,5],[3,4]]
```

How do I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: -1: refrain from naming variables to built-ins

Comment: @Volatility, no oder does not matter.

Comment: @abhijit, it is just an example, not real code.

Comment: Even so, you shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Order Matters you can always use OrderedDict

```
>>> unq_lst = OrderedDict()
>>> for e in lst:
    unq_lst.setdefault(frozenset(e),[]).append(e)


>>> map(list, unq_lst.keys())
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
lst=[[1,2],[4,5],[3,4],[4,3],[2,1],[1,2]]
fset = set(frozenset(x) for x in lst)
lst = [list(x) for x in fset]
```

This won't preserve order from your original list, nor will it preserve order of your sublists.

```
>>> lst=[[1,2],[4,5],[3,4],[4,3],[2,1],[1,2]]
>>> fset = set(frozenset(x) for x in lst)
>>> lst = [list(x) for x in fset]
>>> lst
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Not exactly, assume you have `[0,0]` in your `lst`, this will be collapsed to `[0]`.

Comment: That's true.  If you're gauranteed that the inputs always have only 2 items and you want to preserve that in the output, it's pretty easy to post-process to turn the 1-element lists into 2-element lists :)

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important:

```
def rem_dup(l: List[List[Any]]) -> List[List[Any]]:
    tuples = map(lambda t: tuple(sorted(t)), l)
    return [list(t) for t in set(tuples)]
```