# Removing the lists from a list which are duplicated for some items

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove the lists from a list which have same first and third items but only keeping the first one. Example list and output:

```
li=[ [2,4,5], [1,3,5], [1,6,5] ]
output_list = [ [2,4,5], [1,3,5] ]
```

The code I've written takes a very long time to execute as the original list contains millions of list.

```
b_li = []
output_list = []
for x in li:
    s = [ x[0], x[2] ]
    if s not in b_li:
        b_li.append(s)
        output_list.append(x)
```

How can I improve the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a set instead of a list to record seen first/last pairs.

Comment: Depending on your use, you can return an iterator instead of create a new list. It will save you a lot of memory.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037226/python-remove-duplicate-items-from-nested-list?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An improved version:

```
b_li = set()
output_list = []
b_li_add = b_li.add
output_list_append = output_list.append
for x in li:
    s = (x[0], x[2])
    if s not in b_li:
        b_li_add(s)
        output_list_append(x)
```

The changes are:

- Use a `set()` for `b_li` which makes lookups faster.
- Turn `s` into a tuple as there is no need to store unique first and third elements as lists.
- Reduced function lookups which speeds up the code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a set for storing the seen elements. That is faster:

```
seen = set()
res = []
for entry in li:
    cond = (entry[0], entry[2])
    if cond not in seen:
        res.append(entry)
        seen.add(cond)


[[2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
```

**ADDITION**

Also, the time spend on thinking about telling variables names is typically well spend. Often things first though of as throw-away solutions stick around much longer than anticipated.

Comment: Thanks, It was a giant leap :)

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging `OrderedDict` and the fact that dictionaries have unique keys.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> li=[ [2,4,5], [1,3,5], [1,6,5] ]
>>> OrderedDict(((x[0], x[2]), x) for x in reversed(li)).values()
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on @iurisilvio's iterator comment and which uses `itertools.compress` in conjunction with the `set`-based solutions from the others.
Instead of building up an `output_list` from elements in the input list, a `selector` list comprising Boolean values is built up on a one:one basis with respect to elements from the input list. A value of `True` indicates that the corresponding element from the input list should be retained in the output. The `selector` can then be applied on the input list via `itertools.compress` to product an output iterable.

```
from itertools import compress
li=[ [2,4,5], [1,3,5], [1,6,5] ]
b_li = set()
selectors = []
for x in li:
    s = (x[0], x[2])
    if s not in b_li:
        b_li.add(s)
        selectors.append(True)
    else:
        selectors.append(False)

for x in compress(li, selectors):
  print x
[2, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 5]
```