# Get the duplicate elements from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Suppose that I have a list of lists, e.g.

```
example_list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [5, 4]]
```

I want a reasonably fast method of obtaining a list formed exclusively of elements that appear at least twice in the original list. In this example, the new list would be

```
new_list = [[0, 1]]
```

since [0, 1] is the only duplicate entry. I have spent lots of time on Stackoverflow looking for a solution, but none of them seem to work for me (details below). How should I proceed in this instance?

---

*Unsuccessful attempts*. One solution which does work is to write something like

```
new_list = [x for x in example_list if example_list.count(x) > 1]
```

However, this is too slow for my purposes.

Another solution (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811418/finding-duplicates-in-a-list-of-lists)) is to write

```
totals = {}
for k,v in example_list:
  totals[k] = totals.get(k,0) + v
totals.items()
[list(t) for t in totals.items()]
print(totals)
```

I may have misunderstood what the author is suggesting, but this doesn't work for me at all: it prints `{0: 2, 5: 4}` in the terminal.

A final solution (also suggested on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811418/finding-duplicates-in-a-list-of-lists)) is import Counter from collections and write

```
new_list = Counter(x for x, new_list in example_list for _ in xrange(new_list))
map(list, new_list.iteritems())
```

This flags an error on xrange and iteritems (I think it's a Python3 thing?), so I tried

```
new_list = Counter(x for x, new_list in example_list for _ in range(new_list))
map(list, new_list.items())
```

which yielded `Counter({5: 4, 0: 2})` (**again!!**), which is of course not what I am after...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` to create a dictionary of counts of elements in `example_list`. But each element should be converted to a `tuple` to make it hashable. Then, you can filter the elements that meet your criteria.

```
from collections import Counter


d = Counter([tuple(x) for x in example_list])
[list(k) for k, v in d.items() if v >= 2]
# [[0, 1]]
```

Comment: @d.b. Thanks, but that appears to produce [0, 1], as opposed to [[0, 1]]. Is it easy to fix this? It's a bit of an issue. For example, if the example list is [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]], then I want to get [[0, 0], [1, 1]], but your code gives me [0, 1]!

Answer (score 0):

You could count the values of the inner lists. First, is to iterate the list - but really you want to iterate the values of the outer list. `itertools.chain.from_iterable` does that for you. Feed it in `collections.Counter` and you get a count of all of the values. A list comprehension can select the values you want and then place that in an outer list.

```
>>> example_list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [5, 4]]
>>> import collections
>>> import itertools
>>> counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(example_list))
>>> counts
Counter({0: 4, 1: 2, 5: 1, 4: 1})
>>> selected = [k for k,v in counts.items() if v >= 2]
>>> result = [selected]
>>> result
[[0, 1]]
```