# Remove duplicates in nested list (without removing duplicated elements in sublists)

Tags: python, list, nested, duplicates, nested-lists

I am trying to remove duplicated sublists from a nested list that looks like this:

```
result_set = [
    ['MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS'],
    ['Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics'],
    ['Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Clean-Room Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication'],
    ['Photolithography', 'Photolithography', 'Lithography', 'Photolithography'],
    ['MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS']
    ]
```

The output I would like is the following:

```
result_set = [
    ['MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS'],
    ['Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics'],
    ['Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Clean-Room Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication'],
    ['Photolithography', 'Photolithography', 'Lithography', 'Photolithography']
    ]
```

Note that basically the last element ['MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS'] is no longer there. [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037226/python-remove-duplicate-items-from-nested-list) have been asked and I adapted the following code from there:

```
result_set = set(frozenset(x) for x in result)
lst = [list(x) for x in result_set]
```

My problem is that I get the following output:

```
 result_set = [['MEMS'], ['Microfluidics'], ['Microfabrication', 'Clean-Room Microfabrication'], ['Photolithography', 'Lithography']]
```

Notice it also removes the duplicated elements within the sublist. I do not want this because my goal afterwards is to plot a histogram. Say for instance -> MEMS has 4 ocurrences. Therefore I want to keep track of the number of elements each sublist had initially.

Answer (score 2):

If order does not matter, you can use a `set`:

```
final_data = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, result_set))))
```

Output:

```
[['Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Clean-Room Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication'], ['Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics'], ['Photolithography', 'Photolithography', 'Lithography', 'Photolithography'], ['MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS']]
```

If order does matter, you can try this:

```
final_data = []
for result in result_set:
    if result not in final_data:
         final_data.append(result)
```

Output:

```
[['MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS', 'MEMS'], ['Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics', 'Microfluidics'], ['Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Clean-Room Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication', 'Microfabrication'], ['Photolithography', 'Photolithography', 'Lithography', 'Photolithography']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list then make a new list using the keys generated by [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
import itertools
result_set.sort()
new_set = [k for k,g in itertools.groupby(result_set)]
```