# pandas fill a dataframe according to column and row value operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, indexing

Let's say that I have this dataframe:

```
,,,,,,
,,2.0,,,,
,2.0,,2.23606797749979,,,
,,2.23606797749979,,,2.0,
,,,,,2.23606797749979,
,,,2.0,2.23606797749979,,
,,,,,,
```

[image]

I would like to get a two dimensional vector with values of the indexes and the columns of each element which is not nan.

For example, in this case, I am expecting:

```
[[2,1],[1,2],[3,2],[2,3],[5,3],[3,5],[4,5],[5,4]].
```

I am thinking about using iloc and the np.where functions but I am not able to merge the two concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove missing values, if necessary add [`Series.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.swaplevel.html) and in list comprehension convert nested tuples to lists:

```
L = [list(y) for y in df.stack().swaplevel().index]
print (L)
[[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [5, 3], [5, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Or if use indices after `np.where` solution is similar:

```
r, c = np.where(df.notna())
L = [list(x) for x in zip(c, r)]
print (L)
[[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [5, 3], [5, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate the pairs made by the same couple. I mean, instead of having [2,1] and [1,2] just [1,2]. Maybe another post is more appropriate. What do you think?

Comment: @diedro sorry, I am on phone only, possible solution is `https://stackoverflow.com/a/15037238`